# Vocabulary related to the nose

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

What are the most common ways of saying:

- to blow one's nose
- to pick one's nose
- stuffy nose
- runny nose
- nasal congestion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- **to blow one's nose**: Sonarse la nariz, limpiarse los mocos, sonarse los mocos, sonarse.
- **to pick one's nose**: Meterse el dedo en la nariz.
- **stuffy nose**: Nariz congestionada, nariz tapada, nariz taponada, taponamiento de la nariz.
- **to have a runny nose**: tener moqueo nasal, tener moquera, tener moquillo, nariz que moquea, rinorrea (technical name for rhinorrhea).
- **nasal congestion**: Congestión nasal.